# Wordpress php else if statement with advanced custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm trying to make an `if-else-statement` which works by going if there is a link print it around the name.

I have the below code which is almost there. However, the link is being printed above the text ranther than being an actual link.

```
<?php if( the_sub_field('corporate_link') ){ ?>

<a href="<?php the_sub_field('corporate_link'); ?>" 
   target="_blank" 
   title="<?php the_field('corporate_name'); ?>"><?php the_field('corporate_name'); ?></a>

<?php } else { ?>

<?php the_sub_field('corporate_name'); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Any thoughts on how to make it link instead of printing the link if it`s there?

So what im looking to acheive is if there is a link print this

```
 <a href="<?php the_sub_field('corporate_link'); ?>">Coprate Name</a>
```

If there isn't a link it just shows the corporate name.

Comment: I think `the_sub_field('corporate_link')` is not return any value, and it's always false. But this function print to output buffer. Because, you get it above

Comment: What do you get when you print `the_sub_field('corporate_link')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **get_sub_field('corporate_link')** instead of **the_sub_field('corporate_link')**

```
<?php 
   $corporate_link = get_sub_field('corporate_link');
   $corporate_name = get_sub_field('corporate_name');

  if( $corporate_link != '' ){ ?>

   <a href="<?php echo $corporate_link; ?>" 
   target="_blank" 
   title="<?php echo $corporate_name; ?>"><?php echo $corporate_name; ?></a>

 <?php } else { ?>

 <?php echo $corporate_name; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `get_sub_field()` and `get_field()` instead of `the_sub_field()` and `the_field()`